# Why the cloud spanner library for Java perform `ExecuteStreamingSql` instead of `ExecuteSql` when it calls read query?

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

I doesn't have any trouble about it, but just I'd like to know the difference of `ExecuteStreamingSql` and `ExecuteSql` by understanding why the library uses `ExecuteStreamingSql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important reason is that `ExecuteSql` has a [hard upper limit](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Spanner.ExecuteSql) for the size of the returned results of 10MiB. So larger query results must always be returned using `ExecuteStreamingSql`.

In addition, `ExecuteStreamingSql` returns the results as a stream of results, and allows retrying from a specific point in the stream using a `ResumeToken` if the stream / network connection breaks halfway.